# The most efficient way to read a file into a list of strings

Tags: erlang

What is the most efficient way from the time consumed to read a text file into a list of binary strings in erlang ? The obvious solution

```
-module(test).
-export([run/1]).

open_file(FileName, Mode) ->
    {ok, Device} = file:open(FileName, [Mode, binary]),
    Device.

close_file(Device) ->
    ok = file:close(Device).

read_lines(Device, L) ->
    case io:get_line(Device, L) of
        eof ->
            lists:reverse(L);
        String ->
            read_lines(Device, [String | L])
    end.

run(InputFileName) ->
    Device = open_file(InputFileName, read),
    Data = read_lines(Device, []),
    close_file(Device),
    io:format("Read ~p lines~n", [length(Data)]).
```

becomes too slow when the file contains more than 100000 lines.

Comment: why are you passing in the read content to get_line as prompt?

Comment: @Zed, that was my mistake. Now all is working with acceptable speed. Thank you! Sometimes I wish erlang had a strong type system...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
{ok, Bin} = file:read_file(Filename).
```

or if you need the contents line by line

```
read(File) ->
    case file:read_line(File) of
        {ok, Data} -> [Data | read(File)];
        eof        -> []
    end.
```

Comment: how does file:read know in next iteration that is going to be the File with the line that was already read? @Zed

Answer (score 3):

read the entire file in into a binary. Convert to a list and rip out the lines.

This is far more efficient than any other method. If you don't believe me time
it.

```
file2lines(File) ->
   {ok, Bin} = file:read_file(File),
   string2lines(binary_to_list(bin), []).

string2lines("\n" ++ Str, Acc) -> [reverse([$\n|Acc]) | string2lines(Str,[])];
string2lines([H|T], Acc)       -> string2lines(T, [H|Acc]);
string2lines([], Acc)          -> [reverse(Acc)].
```